# When defining a custom file type in a Jetbrains IDE, how can I define how to identify names?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

#### Background

- I'm using PyCharm to look at script files used in the PC game Operation Flashpoint to create custom missions.
- I want to create custom File Types in PyCharm that will let me use PyCharm's various features for the script files used by the game.

#### Problem

I want to be able to middle-mouse-click on a variable or function name and have PyCharm show me where that variable is used.

What I want to be able to do (this example is from Python):
[image]

What I'm currently seeing when I middle-mouse-click on a variable name:
[image]

Regarding the identification of function names: note that these script files don't really have functions in the Python sense; they have labels that the user can have the program jump to using "goto" statements.  Example:

```
#ExampleLabelName
    <do some stuff>
    goto "SomeOtherLabelName"
```

Comment: You can't do it via the custom file type, make a language plug-in instead: https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html.